# Is it possible to modify existing elements?

Tags: jekyll, polymer

I am building a blog with jekyll. I would like to insert a link next each heading on the page but I have no easy way to modify the output HTML. Is there an alternative to `is`

```
<h1 is="x-link"></h1>
```

which doesn't require extra markup and allows me to target all `h*` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to Polymer.

On [polymer-project.org](http://polymer-project.org) we add anchor links to all headings. It's done client-side and the page has control whether or not it displays them using [`add_permalinks`](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/blob/master/_config.yml#L31) variable.

See:

- https://github.com/Polymer/docs/blob/master/_config.yml#L31
- https://github.com/Polymer/docs/tree/master/docs/elements/index.md
- https://github.com/Polymer/docs/tree/master/js/app.js#L18

It's also worth noting the Kramdown markdown engine has support for [inline attributes on block elements](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#inline-attributes). So you can do something like this:

```
# Heading
{:is="x-link"}
```

I might switch things over now that I know that works. Good idea :)

Comment: Switch to what? The `{:is="x-link"}` syntax? That seems redundant, You would have to do it for every header!

Comment: You can create `is=""` elements programmatically using `var link = document.createElement('h1', 'x-link')` -> `<h1 is="x-link">` but you cannot set the `is` attribute later to upgrade the element. It needs to be created or declared as such. Also note, type extension custom elements need to inherit from the correct prototype, so x-link needs to be created from an `HTMLHeadingElement`. Demo: http://jsbin.com/fenaxowa/1/edit